# Change label text on button using values from tuple click tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a list of strings sorted in a tuple like this:

```
values = ('1.Python','2.Ruby','3.PHP','4.Perl','5.JavaScript')
```

My simple code is:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
values = ('1.Python','2.Ruby','3.PHP','4.Perl','5.JavaScript')

ru = Button(root,
            text="Next",
            )
ru.grid(column=0,row=0)

lab = Label(root,
            text=values[0])
lab.grid(column=1,row=0)

ru2 = Button(root,
             text="Previous"
             )
ru2.grid(column=2,row=0)

root.mainloop()
```

I have two tkinter buttons "next" and "previous", the `text` value of the Label is directly taken from the tuple (`text=value[0]`), however I would want to know how to show the next string from the tuple when the next button is pressed, and how to change it to the previous values when the "previous" button is pressed. I know it can be done using for-loop but I cannot figure out how to implement that. I am new to python.

Comment: Look into the `Button` [documentation](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm). They give a nice example of the `command` argument

Comment: use `Button(..., command=callback)` to assing function (callback = function name without `()`) which will change text in `Label` - `lab["text"] = values[some_index]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Button(..., command=callback)` to assign function which will change text in label `lab["text"] = "new text"`

`callback` means function name without `()`

You will have to use `global` inside `function` to inform function to assign `current += 1` to external variable, not search local one.

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def set_next():
    global current

    if current < len(values)-1:
        current += 1
        lab["text"] = values[current]

def set_prev():
    global current

    if current > 0:
        current -= 1
        lab["text"] = values[current]

# --- main ---

values = ('1.Python','2.Ruby','3.PHP','4.Perl','5.JavaScript')
current = 0

root = tk.Tk()

ru = tk.Button(root, text="Next", command=set_next)
ru.grid(column=0, row=0)

lab = tk.Label(root, text=values[current])
lab.grid(column=1, row=0)

ru2 = tk.Button(root, text="Previous", command=set_prev)
ru2.grid(column=2, row=0)

root.mainloop()
```

---

BTW: if `Next` has to show first element after last one

```
def set_next():
    global current

    current = (current + 1) % len(values)
    lab["text"] = values[current]

def set_prev():
    global current

    current = (current - 1) % len(values)
    lab["text"] = values[current]
```